# React Component Image Issue

Tags: reactjs

My image Component won't seem to actually put the image in, the URL is correct as I can add it by physically adding the HTML into the page.
The component seems to be failing. I tried what I found at http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions
but it did not help.

```js
export default class mainLogo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src = {'/src/app/assets/images/home/mainLogo.png'}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the src Url as usual attribute, like this:
<img src="/src/app/assets/images/home/mainLogo.png" />

Comment: that is how i did it before and it didn't render. just gave
`<mainlogo data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1"></mainlogo>`

Comment: I have solved it now actually, in another file where I imported i did `import mainLogo from '../Components/mainLogo.js';` and React Components need to start with a Capital. How do i close this?

Answer (score 0):

The class name should start with a capital letter (MainLogo) and you shouldn't use {} on the src, because you are sending the img url directly to the src. It's not a variable or state.

This should work:

```
export default class MainLogo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src='/src/app/assets/images/home/mainLogo.png' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```